# logistic regression predicts "NA" probability in R - why?

Tags: r, prediction, logistic-regression

I have run a logistic regression in R using the following code:

```
   logistic.train.model3 <- glm(josh.model2, family=binomial(link=logit), data=auth, na.action = na.exclude)
    print(summary(logistic.train.model3))
```

My response variable is binary, taking on values of 1 or 0.

when I look at the summary, everything looks fine, every variable has a coefficient.

However, when I try to output the predicted probabilities using the following code:

`auth$predict.train.logistic <- predict(logistic.train.model3, type = "response")`

Almost 20% of my predictions are "NA". How can this be? What is going on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `NA` in your variables? If so, you'll get `NA` for predict value.