# RRF model is giving NA for test set

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction

I am working on a regression problem . 
I am using RRF in R to implement the problem . 
I made two different data sets one for training and other for testing .

```
    library(RRF)
    train=read.csv('training_data.csv'.header=F)
    model <- RRF(as.numeric(V128) ~ .,data=train, flagReg = 1,importance=TRUE,ntree=1000, keep.forest=TRUE,type=regression,na.action=na.roughfix)
    print(model)
    Call:
    RRF(formula = as.numeric(V128) ~ ., data = train, flagReg = 1,         importance = TRUE, ntree = 1000, keep.forest = TRUE, type = regression,      na.action = na.roughfix) 
           Type of random forest: regression
                 Number of trees: 1000
    No. of variables tried at each split: 2656

    Mean of squared residuals: 0.03509357
                % Var explained: 81.5
```

Now when I am using this model to predict for test set .

```
    test = read.csv('testing_data.csv',header=F)
    predict(model,test,type="response")
```

It is giving NA for all the test data set . 
When I try it for train data set it's still giving me the same. Which I didn't expect at all.

When I run

```
    predict(model,new_data=test,type="response")
```

or

```
    predict(model,new_data=train,type="response")
```

The out-of-bag prediction in object is returned . Which implies data not given . 
What should I do to get the prediction ? After that I also want to find the accuracy or performance for predictions .

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently going through the same problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23276395/4281529) has already helped me identify the cause of NA predicted probabilities. Short(er) answer: there are NAs in your features (or predictors).

I'm also looking for a solution for the rest of the modeling process. When I have enough information to address the rest of your questions, I'll come back to update this answer.

Rumba...